# How do I estimate the parameters of a bivariate normal distribution in R from real data?

Tags: r

I have a set of x-y pairs from real data that I want to model with a bivariate normal distribution, made up of two normal distributions X and Y. I want to calculate the parameters so that I can recreate the distribution without having to use the original source data as it is too expensive (a million rows).

At the moment I am successfully plotting this data with:

```
hexbinplot(x~y, data=xyPairs, xbins=16)
```

I think I need to estimate the following parameters:

- Mean of distribution X
- Standard deviation of distribution X
- Mean of distribution Y
- Standard deviation of distribution Y
- Rho, which is used to create a Sigma matrix

Then the bivariate normal is specified with:

[image: Bivariate normal distribution parameters]

Is there a package to do this in R?

I have looked through a number of packages but most of them help you simulate a bivariate with random data, instead of helping you create a bivariate normal distribution that models real data.

Please let me know if you would like any more details.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Ok, so let's start with a few facts:

1. If you have a multivariate normal distribution, the marginal distributions do not depend on any parameters related to variables that have been marginalized out. See [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multivariate_normal_distribution#Marginal_distributions)
2. The maximum likelihood estimators for the parameters `mu` and `sigma^2` are well known to correspond to the sample analogues. See [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maximum_likelihood#Continuous_distribution.2C_continuous_parameter_space) for an example about how to get the analytical solutions in the univariate case.

This leads us to the conclusion you can estimate these parameters the following way. First, let me generate some sample data:

```
n <- 10000
set.seed(123) #for reproducible results
dat <- MASS::mvrnorm(n=n, 
               mu=c(5, 10), 
               Sigma= matrix(c(1,0.5,0.5,2), byrow=T, ncol=2)
)
```

Here, I have chosen `mu1` and `mu2` to be 5 and 10, respectively. Also, `sigma1^2` equals 1, `rho*sigma1*sigma2` equal 0.5, and `sigma2^2` equals 2. Note that since `rho * sigma1 * sigma2 = 0.5`, we have that `rho = 0.5/sqrt(1*2) = 0.35`

**Using known (analytical) Maximum Likelihood Estimators**

Now, let us estimate the parameters `mu1` and `mu2` from the data first. Here, I use the sample means of each individual variable, since fact 1 ensures that I don't need to worry about dependencies. That is, I can ignore that they are bivariately normal, since the marginal distributions have identical parameters, and I happen to know that the MLE for these parameters in the univariate case are the sample means.

```
> colMeans(dat)
[1]  5.006143 9.993642
```

We see that this comes pretty close to the true values that we have specified earlier when generating the data.

Now, let us estimate the variances of `x1` and `x2`:

```
> apply(dat, 2, var)
[1] 0.9956085 2.0008649
```

Also, this comes pretty close to the true values. This approach seems to work well so far. :)

Now, all that is left is `rho`: Notice that the entry on the off-diagonal of the variance covariance matrix is `rho*sigma1*sigma2 = rho * 1 * sqrt(2)`, which I defined to be 0.5. Hence, `rho = 0.35`.

Now, let us take a look at the sample correlation. The sample correlation already standardizes the covariance, so we do not need to manually divide by `sqrt(2)` to get the correlation coefficient.

```
 > cor(dat)
          [,1]      [,2]
[1,] 1.0000000 0.3481344
[2,] 0.3481344 1.0000000
```

which is again pretty close to the previously specified true parameter. Note that one could argue that the latter is biased in small samples and we could make a correction. See the Wikipedia article for a discussion. If you wanted to do that, you would just multiply the last term with `n/(n-1)`. With sample sizes such as `n=10000`, it typically does not make a big difference.

Now, what have I done here? I knew how the analytical maximum likelihood estimators for these quantities look like, and I have just used them to estimate these parameters. What would you do if you did not know how the solution looks like analytically? In principle, you know the likelihood function. You have the data. You could write up the likelihood function as a function of the parameters, and then just use one of the many available optimizers to find the values of the parameters that maximize the sample likelihood. This would be the direct ML approach. See [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maximum_likelihood#Continuous_distribution.2C_continuous_parameter_space).

So, let's try it.

**Maximizing the Likelihood numerically**

The above procedure used the fact that we were able to analytically obtain the maximum likelihood estimators. That is, we found closed form solutions for these quantities by taken the derivative of the likelihood function, setting it equal to zero, and solving for the unknown quantities. However, we can also use the computer to find the values numerically, which may come in handy in case you can't find tractable analytical solutions. Let's try that.

First, since we are going to maximize a function, let's use the built-in function `optim` for that. `optim` requires me to supply a parameter vector with inital starting values, and a function that takes a parameter vector as argument. The function is supposed to return a value which is to be maximized or minimized.

This function will be the sample likelihood. Given an iid-sample of size `n`, the sample likelihood is the product of all `n` individual likelihoods (i.e. the probability density functions). Numerical optimization of a large product is possible, but people typically take the logarithm to turn the product into a sum. To get the likelihood, just stare look long and hard at the individual pdf of a bivariate normal distribution, and you will see that the sample likelihood can be written as

```
-n*(log(sig1) + log(sig2) + 0.5*log(1-rho^2)) - 
0.5/(1-rho^2)*( sum((x1-mu1)^2)/sig1^2 + 
                sum((x2-mu2)^2)/sig2^2 - 
                2*rho*sum((x1-mu1)*(x2-mu2))/(sig1*sig2) )
```

This function is to be maximized over its arguments. Since `optim` requires me to supply one parameter vector, I use a wrapper for this and set the maximization problem up as follows:

```
wrap <- function(parms, dat){
  mymu1  = parms[1]
  mymu2  = parms[2]
  mysig1 = parms[3]
  mysig2 = parms[4]
  myrho  = parms[5]
  myx1 <- dat[,1]
  myx2 <- dat[,2]
  n = length(myx1)

  f <- function(x1=myx1, x2=myx2, mu1=mymu1, mu2=mymu2, sig1=mysig1, sig2=mysig2, rho=myrho){
    -n*(log(sig1) + log(sig2) + 0.5*log(1-rho^2)) - 0.5/(1-rho^2)*(
      sum((x1-mu1)^2)/sig1^2 + sum((x2-mu2)^2)/sig2^2 - 2*rho*sum((x1-mu1)*(x2-mu2))/(sig1*sig2)
      )
  }
  f(x1=myx1, x2=myx2, mu1=mymu1, mu2=mymu2, sig1=mysig1, sig2=mysig2, rho=myrho)

  }
```

My call to `optim` then looks as follows:

```
eps <- eps <- .Machine$double.eps  # get a small value for bounding the paramter space to avoid things such as log(0).

numML <- optim(rep(0.5,5), wrap, dat=dat, 
         method="L-BFGS-B", 
         lower = c(-Inf, -Inf, eps, eps, -1+eps), 
         upper = c(Inf, Inf, 100, 100, 1-eps), 
         control = list(fnscale=-1))
```

Here, `rep(0.5,5)` provides starting values, `wrap` is above function, `lower` and `upper` are bounds on the parameters, and the `fnscale` argument makes sure we are maximizing the function. As outcome, I get:

```
numML$par 
[1]  5.0061398 9.9936433 0.9977539 1.4144453 0.3481296
```

Note that these elements correspond to `mu1`, `mu2`, `sig1`, `sig2` and `rho`. If you square `sig1` and `sig2`, you see that we recreate the variances that I have supplied originally. So, it seems to work. :)

Comment: Thanks, this is really helpful. :-) My rho is lower than I expect (rho~0.01 when R2~0.2). When you mentioned "take a look at the sample covariance", why are you using `cor` instead of `cov`? Is that correct or is rho simply `cor(dat)[2,1]`?

Comment: Of course you are right. That was a typo combined with a simple math error. Thanks for pointing that out! I also added how to do the numerical optimization just for completeness.

Comment: Regarding your question "What would you do if you did not know how the solution looks like analytically?" When would this be the case? Is plotting the data enough to "know how the solution looks"? Sorry about my ignorance - I'm just trying to fully understand the pros and cons of the two estimations and which one I should use. Thanks again :-)

Comment: Let me rephrase this: can you find the value of `x` that maximizes the function `f(x) = - x^2`? How would we find the solution? We would take the first derivative, set it equal to zero, and solve for x. In this case, we will find that `x=0` is the analytical solution. If the functional form was different and more complicated, we might not be able to solve for `x`, though. Then we would have to use numerical maximization.

Comment: Will maximizing the likelihood numerically reduce the training error in comparison to using known maximum likelihood estimators? My understanding from your answer is that the numerical approach is useful for more complex models (e.g. not bivariate) where it is harder to estimate the parameters but it won't give us a better model in this case. Is that correct?

Comment: For more complex models, you will simply not be able to find analytical expressions for the values of your parameter vector that maximize the likelihood. For `f(x) = -x^2` you can find the max by looking at the function, or by taking the derivative and setting it to zero, and solving for `x`. For a function such as `f(x) = x^5 + x^4 + e^-x + sin(x)^{1/(1-x^alpha)} + ln(1+e^x) + 5x`, that is much harder and probably impossible, so finding the max numerically is much easier.

Comment: The standard errors should be roughly the same, though I could imagine that standard errors for the elements in the variance covariance matrix may be slightly different (since they depend on the estimated mean). That is a rather subtle point though and I am not sure how much one should worry about it. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Likelihood_function#Profile_likelihood

Comment: Update the Lik function from `f <- ... {
    -n*(log(sig1) + log(sig2) - 0.5*log(1-rho^2)) - 0.5/(1-rho^2)*(...)` to `f <- ...{
    -n*(log(sig1) + log(sig2) + 0.5*log(1-rho^2)) - 0.5/(1-rho^2)*(... )`